# Foreach with Insert SQL (C#, SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, insert

I have list of values:

```
string[] DataValues
```

now I want to put all the value into insert:

```
string myInsert = "Insert into table1(col1, col2, col3....col4) values (DataValues[0],DataValues [1], DataValues[2]....)
```

It's posssible to use somehow foreach?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Doesnt even make that huge difference in code, since you can easily *convert* the code with a `for` loop to code with a `foreach` loop, or the other way round.

Comment: foreach (string s in DataValues)  { //insert s into database; }

Comment: Why not just use the [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: If you are creating SQL like this, you are going to open yourself up to SQL injection and bugs. Please be very careful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get exactly what your want you can format your DataValues like so:

```
var paramList = string.Join(",",DataValues.Select(x=>string.Format("'{0}'",x)).ToArray()
```

I presume you have the same for columns list.

BUT DO NOT DO THAT

this will make your code prone to sql injection you should declare parameter for each value and use it via parameter.

```
var parameters = string.Join(",",DataValues.Select((x,i)=>"@param"+i));
var myInsert = string.Format("Insert into table1({0}) values ({1})", columns, parameters);

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    for(var i=0; i< DataValues.Length ; i++)
    {
       var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@param"+i,  SqlDbType.NVarChar, DataValues[i].Length);
       param.Value = DataValues[i];
    }
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @DavidG yes ok, fixed.

Comment: thx Rafal, the insert command will be saved inside file.sql, so "myInsert" I can easly write to file